# First CSS declaration of code works in internal stylesheet but not external stylesheet

Tags: css

I have a large website that I have maintained for many years entirely in html4. I am beginning to convert it to css. I have an internal styleheet that works fine, but when I move it to an external styleheet the body element rules have no effect. Everything else in the stylesheet works as it did when internal.

I have tried moving just the body element back to the internal header and it works there.

```
body {
    background-color: #E3D7B7; 
    text-color: black;
    font-family: Franklin Gothic Medium, sans-serif;
    font-size: medium;
    line-height: 125%;
}
```

This takes effect when internal, but when external it is ignored--the font, for example, shows as the default.  Everything that follows this in the stylesheet takes effect.

Comment: did you check if you added your link stylesheet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No other stylesheet exists.

I know that it is correctly linked in the html because all the other things in it such as formatting of the navbar are working.

I know that nothing in the stylesheet is overriding it because the same stylesheet works when internal -- all I did to makke it external was cut and paste the entire style section of the header.

I know that nothing inline is overriding it because if it were, it wouldn't work when in the header, and it does.  (It's online at www.sylviaengdahl.com).

I have now tried using !important and it makes no difference.  I still don't get the specified font when it's external.

---

This is really strange.  I copied your css file, which works for you externally, and put it in a test file, then changed my html file to link to it.  It is not in a different folder.  But I still get the default font intead of the one specified, which is a standard Windows font.

To see if it's a font problem, I changed the font color specified to green. That didn't take affect either, so it's the whole body element.

So then I moved body to below the link colors, and now it works! What difference could the poition make?  It's not just because it was first, because the link colors still work.

The css file now works with other html files, which it didn't before. I guess my problem is solved if I put body and link definitions in reverse order externally from the way they've been working internally, but I'd surely like to know why.

Thank you for your help.

---

Update: I was mistaken -- when I reverse the body and link element order, the normal link color does not work although the visited link color does (I didn't notice until I used another browser because I had visited all the links with my first one.) Thus it is just the very first line in the stylesheet that's ignored.
I have proved this by putting a line defining the active link first, which causes the next line, the normal link color, to take effect.

For practical purposes this will fix the problem, as I don't care if the default color is used for active links.  But it doesn't explain what's causing the first line of the stylesheet to be ignored, when it's a pasted copy of the working stylesheet that you posted.

**UPDATE**

I found the answer to my problem.  I had made a beginner's mistake -- I'm new to CSS despite long experience with HTML, and I had never seen any instructions for making an external stylesheet other than to move the CSS out of the header and put it into a new file. So when I did that, I took the style tag with it.  All other files I have dealt with, such as those needed to produce ebooks, contain something at the top identifying the content, so I assumed that since a file containing html starts with html a file containing styles would start with style.  Not until started wondering if I needed any additional information in the header did I discover that a CSS file has no header at all.

I was puzzled so long because everything in the file worked except the first declaration.  But what evidently happened was that the browser didn't know what to do with the superfluous line, so it ignored all code until it came to the first right curly brace, which was at the end of the first declaration.

Answer (score 0):

First, did you added any other stylesheet, such as bootstrap? if you did, depending on the order it may overwrite one another.

as i cannot see your html file i will presume things here, did you correctly added you'r style on the head? all directories are correct?

if the inline body style is taking the higher cascade choice(as it should), then on your external file there is something overwriting it, go for the browser and inspect it. as an experiment put the body into !important on your external file.

```
body {
background-color: #E3D7B7 !important;  
text-color: black;
font-family: Franklin Gothic Medium, sans-serif;
font-size: medium;
line-height: 125%;
```

}

Is your css on a new folder  ex:(css/main.css) ? if it is, it will be necessary to change the src/href of some things, if you are using a font you download you have to say to the css file where to find it again, if the font-imgs are outside of the css folder then "../place/file.typeOfFile"

another thing, did you tried it on more than one browser? the cache of one browser can some times get in the way.

i was successful on putting the css into a external file, all fonts are working, tho, on your code there were some problems, the only things here missing are the imgs since i did not downloaded them.

```css
body {
    background-color: #E3D7B7; 
    color: black;
    font-family: Franklin Gothic Medium, sans-serif;
    font-size: medium;
    line-height: 125%;
    }
    
    a:link {color: #CC3300;}
    a:visited {color: #000066}
    
    img.align-left { 
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 2em;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 1.75em;
    width: 35%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    float: left; 
    }
    
    img.align-right { 
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 2em;
    margin-left: 1.75em;
    margin-right: 0;
    width: 35%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    float: right; 
    }
    
    .clear { clear: both;
    }
    
    .center { text-align: center; margin-bottom: 1.3em;" /* delete the " " here */
    }
    
    @media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    body {background-image: url("images/universe-bg.jpg");}
    }
    
    div {
    width: 95%;
    background-image: url("images/parchment.jpg");
    background-color: #E3D7B7;
    border-color: black;        
    border-style: double;
    border-width: 2px;        
    margin-top: 2%;
    margin-bottom: 2%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding-left: 8px;        
    padding-right: 8px;
    padding-top: 1%;
    }
            
    @media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    div { 
    width: 60%;
    border-width: 5px;
    margin-top: 4%;
    margin-bottom: 0;              
    padding-left: 2.5%;  
    padding-right: 2.5%; } 
    }
    
    .navbar {
    width:98%;
    border: none;
    padding: 0; 
    font-size: medium;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }
    .navbar .navtable, td {
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border: 4px ridge #6EBDAF;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    a.navbar:link { color:black; text-decoration:none; }
    a.navbar:visited { color:black; text-decoration:none; }
    
    @media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    .navbar { width: 66% } 
    }
    
    @media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    h1  { font-size: xlarge; }
    h2  { font-size: large; margin-top: 0; }
    }
    
    @media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    p.variable-size { font-size: large; }
    h1  { font-size: xxlarge: } /* this has to have some value, otherwise its only using the default, if the defaults is working for you, delete this line */
    h2  { font-size: xlarge; margin-top: 0;  }
    }
```

```html
<html><head>
    <title>Sylvia Engdahl, Author of Science Fiction Novels – Official Site</title>
    
    <meta name="description" content="Science fiction author Sylvia Engdahl - her Flame duologies, Young Adult novels such as Enchantress from the Stars, nonfiction & views on space colonization.">
    
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css">
    
    </head>
    
    <body>
    
    <div class="navbar navtable">
    <table width=100% style="border-collapse:collapse;">
    <tr><td colspan=4 style="font-size: medium;"><b>OFFICIAL AUTHOR  SITE OF SYLVIA ENGDAHL</b>
    <tr><td width=25% bgcolor="#6EBDAF"><a class="navbar" href="index.htm"><b>Books</b></a>
    <td width=25%><a class="navbar" href="about.htm"><b>About Me</b></a>
    <td width=25%><a class="navbar" href="se-faq.htm"><b>FAQ </b></a>
    <td width=25%><a class="navbar" href="reviews.htm"><b>Reviews</b></a>
    <tr><td width=25%><a class="navbar" href="essays.htm"><b>Essays etc. </b></a>
    <td width=25%><a class="navbar"  href="space/space.htm"><b>Space</b></a>
    <td width=25%><a class="navbar" href="miscel.htm"><b>Miscellany</b></a>
    <td width=25%><a class="navbar" href="contact.htm"><b> Contact</b></a></table>
    
    </div>
    
    <div>
    
    <br>
    <h1 class="center"><i>The Books of Sylvia Engdahl</i></h1>
    
    Except where otherwise noted, all books are currently available in Kindle, epub, pdf and paperback editions. Click on the book titles for full descriptions including review quotes, FAQs, excerpts, and purchase links. <br><br>
    Click on the tabs above for essays, space advocacy, and much more, such as a page about my <a href="se-cats.htm">cats</a>, a memorial to my <a href="mbe.htm">mother</a>, and an <a href="essays/autobiography.htm">autobiography</a>.<br><br>
    
    I am currently in the process of making this site mobile-friendly. If you reach a page where the borders of the tabs at the top aren't blue, it hasn't been fixed yet--if it doesn't work with your device, please visit with a laptop or desktop computer, or come back later.<br><br>
    <hr><br>
    
    <h2 class="center">Stand-Alone Novels</h2>
    
    <img class="align-left" src="images/efts.jpg"><a href="elana.htm"><h2><i>Enchantress from the Stars</i></h2></a>
    <p class="variable-size">
    Young Adult, for readers age 12 and older. A Newbery Honor Book.<br><br>
    "Original and charming." <i>--Ursula LeGuin, New York Times Book Review</i><br><br> 
    "Not just a novel for young adults but also one of the finest sf novels ever written--a classic of the genre." 
    <i>--InfinityPlus</i><br></p>
    Also available as an audiobook. No pdf edition.
    <hr class="clear"><br>
    
    <img class="align-left" src="images/fsoe.jpg"><a href="fsoe.htm"><h2><i>The Far Side of Evil</i></h2></a>
    <p class="variable-size">
    Young Adult, for high school age readers.<br><br>
    Though this novel has the same heroine as <i>Enchantress from the Stars</i> it is not a "sequel" but an independent and much darker story unsuitable for middle-school readers. Older readers can read them in either order.<br><br>
    "Gripping psychological science fiction." <i>--Times Literary Supplement</i><br></p>
    <hr class="clear"><br>
    
    <img class="align-left" src="images/jbw.jpg"><a href="jbw.htm"><h2><i>Journey Between Worlds</i></h2></a>
    <p class="variable-size">
    Young Adult, for readers age 12 and older.<br><br>
     A romance about the colonization of Mars.<br><br>
    "Beautifully-written, heartwarming, and scientifically plausible." <i>--Orson Scott Card's Intergalactic Medicine Show</i><br></p>
    <hr class="clear"><br>
    
    <h2 class="center"><b>Children of the Star Trilogy</b></h2>
    
    <img class="align-right" src="images/tssa.jpg"><a href="cots.htm"><h2><i>This Star Shall Abide</i></h2></a>
    <p class="variable-size">
    (Book One -- UK title <i>Heritage of the Star</i>)<br><br>
    Young adult, for readers age 12 and older.<br><br>
    Winner of a Christopher Award for "affirmation of the highest values of the human spirit."<br><br>
    "Both logically and consistently suspenseful... This Star will Abide a good deal longer than most here today, gone tomorrow sci-fi." <i>--Kirkus Reviews</i><br></p>
    Also available as an audiobook.
    <hr class="clear"><br>
    
    <img class="align-right" src="images/bttm.jpg"><a href="cots.htm"><h2><i>Beyond the Tomorrow Mountains</i></h2></a>
    <p class="variable-size">
    (Book Two)<br><br>
    Young Adult, for high school age readers.<br><br>
    "Wrestles with deeply adult problems." <i>--Psychology Today</i><br></p>
    No paperback edition.
    <hr class="clear"><br>
    
    <img class="align-right" src="images/dotu.jpg"><a href="cots.htm"><h2><i>The Doors of the Universe</i></h2></a>
    <p class="variable-size">
    (Book Three)<br><br>
    Young Adult, for high school age readers.<br><br>
    "Haunts the reader long after it is finished."  <i>--Journal of Reading</i><br></p>
    No paperback edition.
    <hr class="clear"><br>
    
    <img class="align-right" src="images/cots.jpg"><a href="cots.htm"><h2><i>Children of the Star</i></h2></a>
    <p class="variable-size">
    (Omnibus Edition)<br><br>
    Issued as adult science fiction.<br><br>
    "[The novels were first] marketed as young adult books, but there is nothing juvenile about them.... Engdahl tells an important and pertinent story." <i>--San Jose Mercury News</i><br></p>
    <hr class="clear"><br>
    
    <h2 class="center"><b>Flame Duologies</b></h2>
    
    <img class="align-left" src="images/dotf.jpg"><a href="dotf.htm"><h2><i>Defender of the Flame</i></h2></a>
    <p class="variable-size">
    (<i>The Rising Flame,</i> Book One)<br><br>
    An adult novel, but may be enjoyed by mature high school age readers.<br><br>
    Though published later than the Hidden Flame duology, this one is completely independent and quite different. It is preferred by many adults who like my YA books.<br><br>
    "This book reaches back to the brio and speculation of Engdahl's classic books of the Seventies." <i>--Nicholas Birns, author of </i>J.R.R. Tolkien: Architect of Modern Fantasy<br></p>
    <hr class="clear"><br>
    
    <img class="align-left" src="images/hotf.jpg"><a href="hotf.htm"><h2><i>Herald of the Flame</i></h2></a>
    <p class="variable-size">
    (<i>The Rising Flame,</i> Book Two) <br><br>
    An adult novel, but may be enjoyed by mature high school age readers.<br><br>
     <i>Defender of the Flame</i> should be read first, as this sequel contains spoilers for it.<br><br>
    "A futuristic ride that has many parallels in today’s society. This is a ‘thinking man’s’ science fiction book – the type we need more of today!" <i>--The Feathered Quill</i><br></p>
    <hr class="clear"><br>
    
    <img class="align-left" src="images/trf.jpg" width=35% border="1" hspace="15" vspace="0"  align="left">
    <a href="https://read.amazon.com/kp/embed?asin=B00YE05LUG&preview=newtab&linkCode=kpe&ref_=cm_sw_r_kb_dp_FON1AbF5PZYN9"><h2><i>The Rising Flame</i></h2></a><br>
    <p class="variable-size">
    (Omnibus Edition)<br><br>
    "These novels are not so much genre 'Romance' or even just 'Science Fiction' as they are Literature. These are novels about life." <i>--Jacqueline Lichtenberg, Alien Romances: Reviews 14</i><br></p>
    <hr class="clear"><br>
    
    <img class="align-left" src="images/sotf.jpg"><a href="sotf.htm"><h2><i>Stewards of the Flame</i></h2></a>
    <p class="variable-size">
    (<i>The Hidden Flame,</i> Book One) <br><br>
    An adult novel, unsuitable for young adults.<br><br>
    Though published before the other Flame novels and set earlier in time, this has a more controversial theme and moves more slowly, so is not typical of them.<br><br>
    “The story is compelling ... a thought provoking novel that may make you question the authority and direction of modern Western medical practices." <i>--Blogcritics</i><br></p>
    <hr class="clear"><br>
    
    <img class="align-left" src="images/potf.jpg"><a href="potf.htm"><h2><i>Promise of the Flame</i></h2></a>
    <p class="variable-size">
    (<i>The Hidden Flame,</i> Book Two) <br><br>
    An adult novel, unsuitable for young adults. Some of the content is inappropriate for readers below high school age. 
    <br><br>
    This duology can be read independently of <i>Stewards of the Flame</i>.<br><br>
    "The ideas and futuristic possibilities are disturbingly real and will remain with the reader long after they’ve finished the book.” <i>--IndieReader Staff Review</i><br></p>
    <hr class="clear"><br>
    
    <img class="align-left" src="images/thf.jpg"><a href="https://read.amazon.com/kp/embed?asin=B016IPIEJY&preview=newtab&linkCode=kpe&ref_=cm_sw_r_kb_dp_yJN1Ab5KSCEE5">
    <h2><i>The Hidden Flame</i></h2></a>
    <p class="variable-size">
    (Omnibus Edition)<br><br>
    "Thought-provoking themes, heroic characters, action, and suspense. Once you start reading these, you won't want to put them down." <i>Robert H., Amazon Vine Voice</i><br></p>
    <hr class="clear"><br>
    
    <h2 class="center"><b>Nonfiction</b></h2>
    
    <img class="align-right" src="images/pgs.jpg"><a href="pgs.htm"><h2><i>The Planet-Girded Suns</i></h2></a>
    <p class="variable-size">
    <i>The Long History of Belief in Exoplanets</i><br><br>
    For adults and high school.<br><br>
    
    About the little-known fact that most educated people in the 18th and 19th centuries believed planets of other suns are inhabited.<br><br>
    "Engdahl has marshalled an impressive and fascinating selection of primary sources and ... reminded us that our ancestors entertained a view of the universe that was larger and more imaginative than the history books lead us to believe." <i>--Kirkus Reviews</i><br></p>
    <hr class="clear"><br>
    
    <img class="align-right" src="images/rotf.jpg"><a href="rotf.htm"><h2><i>Reflections on the Future</i></h2></a>
    <p class="variable-size">
    <i>Collected Essays</i><br><br>
    For adults and high school.<br><br>
    Essays about my books, the importance of space colonization, and many other topics, plus an autobiography.
    <br><br>"Full of great ideas some of which have stood the test of time. I would highly recommend it for anyone interested in the possibilities of the future." <i>--Reader review, Amazon UK</i><br></p>
    No paperback edition.<br>
    <hr class="clear"><br>
    
    <h2 class="center"><b>Anthology</b></h2>
    
    <img class="align-right" src="images/anywhen.jpg"><a href="anywhen.htm"><h2><i>Anywhere, Anywhen</i></h2></a>
    <p class="variable-size">
    <i>Stories of Tomorrow</i> (Expanded Edition)<br><br>Young Adult, for ages 12 and older.<br><br>
     Includes all of my short fiction as well as original stories by other authors.<br><br>
    "The stories are well-written, deeply thought out and a pleasure to read." <i>—Sunday Advocate, Baton Rouge, Louisiana</i><br></p>
    No paperback edition.<br>
    
    <br class="clear">
    
    </div>
    
    <div style="margin-top:0%; margin-bottom:3%; padding-top:0;">
    <p class="center" style="font-size: small;">
    Entire site copyright 1997-2019 by Sylvia Engdahl (except where earlier text copyright indicated).<br>
    Last updated April 2, 2019</p>
    
    </div>
    
    <script>
      (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
      (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
      m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
      })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
      ga('create', 'UA-76418036-1', 'auto');
      ga('send', 'pageview');
    </script>
    
    </body></html>
```